# Use LEA (LEAL) to create an x86 assembly counter

Tags: variables, assembly, x86

I'm trying to make an assembly program that adds together an unknown number of int's, like

sum(int a,int b, ...)

My code is

```
.globl notnull

notnull:
    leal    4(%esp),%ebx
    jmp next2
next:
    leal    4(%ebx),%ebx
next2:
    cmp $0,(%ebx)
    je  end
    movl    (%ebx),%eax
    jmp     next
end:
    ret
```

I test it with this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int notnull();

int main()
{
    int x=notnull(3,2,1,0);
    printf("3,2,1,0 = %d\n",x);

    x=notnull(2,1,0);
    printf("2,1,0 = %d\n",x);

    x=notnull(1,0);
    printf("1,0 = %d\n",x);

    x=notnull(0);
    printf("0 = %d\n",x);

    x=notnull();
    printf("_ = %d\n",x);

    return 0;
}
```

Wich gives me this output:

```
3,2,1,0 = 1 (#1)
2,1,0 = 1 (#2)
1,0 = 1 (#3)
0 = 8 (#4)
_ = 8 (#5)
```

What I want is the program to return 0 when there are no variables (see #5), and also make it work without having to have 0 as the last digit.

The perfect output of notnull(3,2) would 2 and notnull()=0

Comment: notnull(1,2) will make 4(%esp)=1 and 8(%esp)=2 and 12(%esp) is unused. How can I determine if 12(%esp) is null/nothing or not?

Answer (score 1):

You need to read up on C argument passing conventions.

Basically, there is no way to automatically determine how many arguments are being passed to a function.

This is why all C functions either have a fixed number of arguments, or if they use variable arguments (varargs) they have one fixed argument *before* the variable part, which somehow expresses how many additional arguments are being passed.

Using an empty argument list makes it possible to validly call the function in any manner, but it doesn't help with the core problem of (in the function) determining how many arguments are available.

You *might* be able to figure it out by inspecting the stack, but of course that requires intimate knowledge of exactly how your particular compiler choses to implement the call. This might vary for different number of arguments, too.

Comment: Do there is noe way that I can compare %esp or %ebx and find out if it's unused?